# Array of objects in Javascript - Struts Forms

Tags: javascript, jsp, object, struts

This is for a web application using struts.

I have an array of objects in my Form that gets listed in a table. A user can add/edit/delete from the table. How would I send the changed table back to the Action class?

Will I need to create a string or array of strings, and parse that into an object? Is there a way that java/struts handles objects that are to be modified in the jsp? Or does this need to be cared for in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts binds the request parameters onto the ActionForm object based on name of the input.

`actionFormObj.setBla(String x) { ... }` matches `<input name="bla"...` in the form.

When you have related inputs, you can use maps or arrays for ActionForm properties and Struts is smart enough to treat them as well. See [here](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/indexedprops.html).

Additionally, if your table contains read-only data that you switch to input when editing, you might have to deal with a lot of hidden fields in your form. If you still consider JavaScript as an option, you could create a POST request based on a JavaScript object (that you create with whatever data you wish from the table) and then use jQuery to send it. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Answer (score 0):

Indexed properties in struts, apparently takes care of this.